# anchor is not redirecting to display inside ng-view, rather reloading with new page

Tags: ng-view

I wrote a simple angular application in a learning purpose. However the controllers are working in my system but not in plunker. But, that is not my concern. My concern is I am unable to see the linked pages inside ng-view. They are rather opening as a new page replacing the home page. Secondly, the expressions are not reflecting their values. Kindly help me out. I have uploaded the codes in plunker.
[Link to Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YCLabifqdc2apxZJBerC?p=info)

```
<div ng-controller="RamFirstCtrl">{{name}}</div>
<div ng-include="'navbar-top.html'"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid green; position:relative;" ng-view></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed couple thing:

1. `http` to `https`, there is error in console, it might be the reason it doesn't work in plunker

   ```
   <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
   ```
2. you have to use the url define in your router:
   `ng-href="aboutUS.html"` to `ng-href="#!/aboutUS"`

   ```
   .when("/aboutUS", {
       templateUrl : "aboutUS.html"
   })

   <div>
      <a ng-href="#!/aboutUS">
           AboutUs
      </a>
   </div>
   ```

   Note:`#!` will be added to url by angular router by default